# What's the transition probability according to this PDE?

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to figure out how I can simulate markov chains based on an ODE:

```
dN/dt = alpha N (1 - N / K) - beta N
```

Thus `N` denotes total population, and I want to simulate through sampling for each present individual `N(t)` if they'd birth new ones `alpha (1-N/k)` or die due to death probability `beta`. I don't want to use exponential distribution for these.. But I don't know what to do when e.g. `beta>1` or `K>N`, as then `alpha(1-N/K)` may not be a proper probability.

Comment: (1) Your model is not stochastic: it's an ordinary differential equation for $N.$  If you are assuming some of these quantities are random, please state those assumptions explicitly. (2) The meaning of "for each $N(t)$ present" is puzzling in this context.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Nothing in this equation is random. I am want to simulate this `N`, by `+/- 1` transitions. So for each individual present at a given time `t`, instead of just simulation how many in total would be birthed (or die with `beta` probability), I want to do it for each one present. Meaning, I cannot use the exponential trick used [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206149/monte-carlo-simulation-using-exponential-distributions)

Comment: Thank you.  I believe my answer in that thread solves your problem.  The reason is that your equation can be re-expressed as $$d/ds (N) = N(1 - N/r)$$ where $s = t/(\alpha-\beta)$ and $r = K(\alpha-\beta)/\alpha$ and that's the equation I used.

Comment: As you have two types of transitions (birth and death) you need to use something like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on additional details in the comments, you have a process with two types of transitions happening with certain rates per unit time (a [birth-death process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process)).  Given the current population size $N$ at time $t$, the transition rates are $\alpha N(1-N/K)$ and $\beta N$, respectively.  It follows that the waiting time $\tau$ to the next transition is exponentially distributed with rate parameter equal to the sum of the current transition rates.  At time $t+\tau$, the process then transitions to state $N+1$ or $N-1$ with probabilities proportional to the transition rates.  This simulation method is known as the [Gillespie algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillespie_algorithm).  An implementation in R follows below.

```r
gillespie <- function(alpha, beta, K, N0, tmax) {
  t <- 0
  N <- N0
  i <- 1
  repeat {
    rates <- c(alpha*N[i]*(1 - N[i]/K), beta*N[i])
    tau <- rexp(1, rate = sum(rates))
    if (t[i] + tau > tmax | N[i]==0)
      break()
    t[i + 1] <- t[i] + tau
    N[i + 1] <- N[i] + sample(c(1, -1), 1, prob = rates)
    i <- i + 1
  }
  data.frame(t,N)
}
set.seed(1)
realization <- gillespie(alpha = .5, beta = .1, K = 20, N0 = 5, tmax = 50)
plot(realization, type="s")
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I've been missing. Absolutely correct. My question is still unanswered though, as `gillespie(alpha = 1, beta = .1, K = 5, N0 = 10, tmax = 100)` will result in `N/K > 1` and the first rate will fail.

Comment: If the birth rate is $\alpha(1-N/K)$, the birth rate becomes zero when $N$ reaches $K$ and thus, $N$ can not grow larger than $N$ so using $N>K$ as initial condition does not make much sense.

Comment: Can I suggest this change?

Comment: @Mossa I would suggest that you first clarify your initial question and also provide some more context as to what your are trying to achieve.   One could of course assume that the birth rate is zero for $N>K$ but the model would then no longer be a stochastic version of the logistic model.

Comment: Understood. Thanks. If this was used in ecological modelling context, it wouldn't be unlikely that the initial population would exceed the carrying capacity, and thus remedying that is not a big problem for me. Of course, I now understand that this breaks the logistic model connection.

Comment: @Mossa One possible remedy that would allow $N>K$ with the expected dynamics still being of the logistic type, would be to instead assume that the birth rate is constant and that the death rate increases linearly with $N$.

Comment: *"it wouldn't be unlikely that the initial population would exceed the carrying capacity"* It would only be likely if the model is false. How could the population get to exceed the carrying capacity in the first place? And will there be zero births? It means that you do not have a time continuous ODE ...

Comment: ... This model seems to be a bit too simplistic. You could change and have the death rate depend on the population size but in the end your equation is just effectively some quadratic function $$\frac{dN}{dt}= \alpha N (1 - N / K) - \beta N = \frac{-\alpha}{K} N^2 + (\alpha-\beta) N$$ and you can change all kinds of interpretations to the parameters $-\alpha/K$ and $\alpha-\beta$, but it is artificial if you do not have a sound ab-initio argumentation for the coefficients in the model.